# gradle build failed with "Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215] failed: Connection refused: connect" error

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, build.gradle

I am trying to do the kafka setup in IntelliJ. but before that as per the instructions I cloned the kafka GIt repository using the GIT bash. Later when I tried to do gradle build, I am getting the connection refused error.

Firewall issue is very much possible. Actually i did the same setup in my personal Macbook and it went like charm. But when I tried the same in my office desktop, it failed. I have pulled in my IT helpdesk team to disable the firewall but they want to know exactly what has to be done in terms of firewall disabling or proxy setup. I am running in Windows10. Below is the exact error message.

I would like to know if anyone have faced similar issue and what has been done to resolve this in terms of proxy or firewall setup.

> $ gradle
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>
> Configure project :
>
> Building project 'core' with Scala version 2.11.12
>
> Building project 'streams-scala' with Scala version 2.11.12
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':core'.
>
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:scoverage'.
>   Could not resolve org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11:1.3.1.
>        Required by: 
>             project :core
>   Could not resolve org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11:1.3.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11/1.3.1/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11-1.3.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11/1.3.1/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11-1.3.1.pom'.
>   Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Could not resolve org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11:1.3.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :core
>   Could not resolve org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11:1.3.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11/1.3.1/scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11-1.3.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11/1.3.1/scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11-1.3.1.pom'.
>   Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215] failed: Connection refused: connect
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 58s

Comment: Looks like firewall/proxy issue: `Connection refused: connect...`